# Django annotate field with queryset of objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Suppose I have two models:

ModelA and ModelB

How can I annotate a queryset of ModelB with objects from ModelA?

`queryset = ModelB.objects.filter(...).annotate(models_a=Subquery(ModelA.objects.filter(...)))`

In order to have `queryset.models_a`as a Queryset of objects ModelA.

Thanks you all!

EDIT:

This are my models:

```py
class Allergen(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Allergen name'), max_length=20, choices=ALLERGENS,
                            help_text=_('Product allergen. Example: gluten'), unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name']


class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=255, help_text=_('Product name'))
    supplier = models.ForeignKey(Supplier, blank=True, null=True, related_name='supplier_products',
                                 on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    allergens = models.ManyToManyField(Allergen, blank=True, related_name='product_allergens')
    unit = models.CharField(_('Unit'), max_length=20, choices=UNITS, default='g')
    price = models.FloatField(_('Sale price'), default=0)
    unit_price = models.FloatField(_('Unit price'))

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['name', ]
        indexes = [models.Index(fields=['name', 'supplier']), ]


class Recipe(models.Model):
    sections = models.ManyToManyField(Section, related_name='recipes', blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(_('Recipe title'), max_length=255, help_text=_('Recipe. Example: american chicken salad'),
                             blank=True)
    unit = models.CharField(_('Unit'), max_length=20, choices=UNITS)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_recipes')

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']
        indexes = [models.Index(fields=['title'])]


class IngredientRecipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=255)
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='ingredients')
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, related_name='ingredient_products')
    quantity = models.FloatField(_('Quantity'))

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']
        unique_together = ('name', 'recipe')
        indexes = [models.Index(fields=['name', 'recipe'])]
```

I'm trying to include the allergens related with the recipe.

Comment: Can you share your models? It sounds like you can use `prefetch_related` here instead of annotate

Comment: Sure! I included my models definition.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with just one recipe, you can just add a model property that returns the related allergens of the recipe by using the reverse relations like this:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    ...

    @property  # or consider using cached_property
    def allergens(self):
        return Allergen.objects.filter(
            product_allergens__ingredient_products__recipe=self,
        )
```

Then you can access the allergens through the instance:

```
recipe = Recipe.objects.first()
print(recipe.allergens)
```